# How to use percentages of screen size to create responsive layouts in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In my app, there is a button that the height of it needs to be precisely 0.2 times the screen height. For example, if the screen size is 1000 px, then its height should be 200 px. No matter the screen size, its height should always be 0.2 times that of the screen.

However, whatever I have done, I cannot get it to be work the same in different screen sizes.

These are my approaches:

**1)Using DP from LocalConfiguration**

```kotlin
// Results in very small for Pixel 2 and almost correct in Pixel 6 emulator
// So small that text in the button disappears and
// seem to took 0.1 of the screen rather than 0.2
Column(
   verticalArragment = Arrangment.SpaceBetween
){
   Text(titleText)
   MyButton(
       modifier = Modifier.height(
           (LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp * 0.2f).dp
       )
   )
}
```

**2)Getting height from context.displayMetrics**

```kotlin
// Results in almost correct on Pixel 2 and very large on Pixel 6 emulators
// So large that more than 0.2 times of the screen height
Column(
   verticalArragment = Arrangment.SpaceBetween
){
   Text(titleText)
   MyButton(
       modifier = Modifier.height(
           (LocalContext.current.displayMetrics.heightPixels * 0.2f).dp
       )
   )
}
```

Additionally, MyButton is not different from the normal button provided by Compose.

Doing the same thing on SwiftUI with GeometryReader or Flutter with MediaQuery.of(context) results in the correct behaviour compared to Compose.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Rafiul yes but the code I presented does not contain the whole screen architecture. The button is inside another view and I want to convert the whole percentage logic to a util class to be used in any composable. So fillMaxHeight is not applicable.

Comment: "there is a button that the height of it needs to be precisely 0.2 times the screen height" -- that will not work well in split-screen modes, Chrome OS/Samsung DeX/other freeform multi-window environments, and possibly foldables.

Answer (score 0):

I have found my mistake even though I wrote it on the post. I am using the Button component supplied by Compose, which has its own padding. This is why it collapses itself along with the content (text) in it. I have changed it to Surface and implemented my custom button and everything worked fine.